# What is the difference between these two versions of the same Template Class

Tags: c++, class, templates, error-handling

What is the difference between these two codes I just don't understand what the problem is.

Version 1 which works perfectly:

```
template <class T>
T max (T& a, T& b)
{
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

int main()
{
    auto i = 2;
    auto j = 3;
    cout << "max(i, j): " << max(i, j) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Version 2 which does not work:

```
template <class T>
T max (T& a, T& b)
{
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

int main()
{

    cout << "max(i, j): " << max(44, 33) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is why does the second version of the same code not work. Can someone tell me what the problem is with it. In the second version the `max(44, 33)` are underlined in red. The error message reads:
`Error C2664: 'T max <int>(T &, T &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int&'(15)` I really don't understand this error and I really want someone to explain why this is happening and how can I fix this. Also when you hover under the max is reads: `no instance of function template max matches the argument list argument types are: (int, int)`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object

Comment: I should add that I am also a beginner to this. So I did not understand anything in that related post :)

Comment: The title of the related post answers your question. In that case you should look into the parts of the title which you don't understand. :)

Comment: @Jacub - When you pass the parameter by reference, the function can change the value of the argument. If the function contains `++a;` that would change `i` from 2 to 3. Should it also be able to change 44 to 45? No! So a long time ago it was decided not to allow passing 44 in a way so that a function might change it.

Comment: Change the template to `T max(const T& a, const T& b)`.